# htaccess rewrite turn all "folders" into request variables, almost got it!

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here's what I have now:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*)$ /$3?$1=$2 [N,QSA]
```

This turns www.any.com**/x/20/y/30** into www.any.com**/index.php?x=20&y=30**

(while ignoring existing directories - thank you so much Gumbo!!)

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*)$ /$3?$1&$2 [N,QSA]
```

This tweak allows me to go: www.any.com**/x/y=30** and accomplish the same results but with x having no value.  I love having this option, but I have to do two variables at a time or I get a page not found for the odd variable.  So www.any.com/x/y=20/z would give me "url /z not found!"

Any thoughts on how I can get it to rewrite basically every folder into a request variable?  Thanks, guys.

Comment: How should `/x/y=20/z` be converted?

Comment: It's my hero again! If it can be done... /x/y=20/z should become /index.php?x&y=20&z or /index.php?x=&y=20&z= I'm sorry if I'm unclear, I'm kind of a n00b. The real issue is that in many cases I just need to send a variable, with no value per se. Like www.any.com/about_us Thanks again Gumbo, I can see you've most definitely earned those many badges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/=]+)=([^/]*)(/(.+))?$ /$4?$1=$2 [N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/=]+)/([^/=]+)(/(.+))?$ /$4?$1=$2 [N,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/=]+)(/(.+))?$ /$3?$1 [N,QSA]
```

#### Explanation:

- **First rule**

  Is to abort the rewriting process if request can be mapped on an existing file or directory.
- **Fecond rule**

  Is for URL paths of the form `/foo=bar/…` → `/…?foo=bar`.
- **Third rule**

  Is for URL paths of the form `/foo/bar/…` → `/…?foo=bar`.
- **Fourth rule**

  Is for URL paths of the form `/foo/…` → `/…?foo`.

Comment: Wow, you really get this stuff.  Perfect, Gumbo.  Thank you once again.

Comment: Hey Gumbo, just wanna say again, this has been solid gold for my project and even my education.  There's only one tiny bug I can see, it's hardly worth mentioning, but if you have any idea why in some browsers this might cause a script to execute twice, I would be all ears.  So far it's just Safari (maybe only on macs) and only on the second, third, fourth, etc reload.  If not I can definitely live with it!

Comment: @Aaron: I can’t image how mod_rewrite could cause that issue. Because all requests are treated as equal. So I think it’s rather Safari that’s requesting the resource twice.

Comment: @Gumbo: ahh, I figured as much... like server languages, browser doesn't matter.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Gumbo, the first conditions/rule seem only to work for direct, NOT relative paths. E.g. if the browser requests <link href="CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> from the main HTML the server will ignore the first conditions/rule. How can this be?!? (Using Chrome on a Mac, but that shouldn't  make any difference, right?!?)

Comment: @Matte mod_rewrite only rewrites request URLs, but not any response data. You need to do the latter yourself.

Comment: @Gumbo, Of course. Major brain fart on my side. Though rewrite is pretty straight forward, it is still so contraintuitive somehow...